# Outlook 2003 and Font-Sizes

Tags: html, email, outlook-2003

I have a html email which works correctly in every client *except* Outlook 2003, where the links have underlines (even with `text-decoration: none;`) and the `font-size` changes to be smaller.

Excerpt from code:

```
<td valign="top" align="left" style="line-height: 31px; font-size: 31px;">
                    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#6b565d" style="line-height: 60px; font-size: 62px;"><strong>25% off</strong></font>
</td>
```

Sample Link:

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="3" color="#ffffff" style="line-height: 16px; font-size: 22px;"><a href="<squeeze.attribute.link.story01_text>" title="Book your sale room now" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-size:22px; background-color: #b50f18;"><font color="#ffffff"><strong>Mooo, I'm some text >></strong></font></a></font>
```

And this `font-size` changes to around 11 or 12px.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lot's of Markup in your code there. I just tried how Outlook 2010's markup looks when sending e-mail - because having links without underline works flawlessly when sending mails to Outlook 2003. Without further ado:

```
<a href="http://example.org">
    <span style='text-decoration:none;'>My Link Text not underlined</span>
</a>
```

The important thing to note: It puts a `span` within the link for styling. No usage of `<font>` whatsoever.

Outlook has the nice "feature" to autocomplete hyperlinks - AFAIK this is only for text you type, but it might be worth a shot, maybe the clients are autocompleting your links to be underlined? (Really just guessing). There is a hotfix to turn of autocompleting links [here](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=904637) ( one still needs to fiddle in the registry and create a DWORD named `DisableAutoUrlCompletion` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Preferences`).

Just for completeness here the full e-mail body of a really simple e-mail sent with Outlook 2010 showing flawlessly in Outlook 2003 (same font size, no underline - all the same). [Bear in mind - lot's of Microsoft "junk" in there which is not really needed, like Calibri styles even though Arial was used]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=
"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns=
"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)" />
  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  <!--
  /* Font Definitions */
  @font-face
  {font-family:Calibri;
  panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
  /* Style Definitions */
  p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
  {margin:0cm;
  margin-bottom:.0001pt;
  font-size:11.0pt;
  font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
  a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
  {mso-style-priority:99;
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;}
  a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
  {mso-style-priority:99;
  color:purple;
  text-decoration:underline;}
  span.EmailStyle17
  {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
  font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
  color:windowtext;}
  .MsoChpDefault
  {mso-style-type:export-only;
  font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
  @page WordSection1
  {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
  margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 2.0cm 70.85pt;}
  div.WordSection1
  {page:WordSection1;}
  -->
  /*]]>*/
  </style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->

  <title></title>
</head>

<body lang="EN-US" link="blue" vlink="purple" xml:lang="EN-US">
  <div class="WordSection1">
    <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="DE" style=
    'font-size:14.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black' xml:lang=
    "DE"><a href="http://example.org/"><span style=
    'color:black;text-decoration:none'>test</span></a></span></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Neurofluxation: Try --

For the excerpt:

```
<td valign="top" align="left">
   <span style="color: #6b565d; font-size: 62px; line-height: 60px;"><strong>25% off</strong></span>
</td>
```

For the link:

```
<a href="<squeeze.attribute.link.story01_text>" title="Book your sale room now" style="background-color: #b50f18; color: #ffffff; font-size: 22px; line-height: 16px; text-decoration: none;"><strong>Mooo, I'm some text &gt;&gt;</strong></a>
```

Here's also a handy guide for CSS support across a multitude of e-mail clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/